# Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados do SQL Server 2012 - usando o servidor IIS 7.5

Tags: sql, servidor

Estou recebendo esse Erro.

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   ).

Esse erro somento ocorre ao tentar conectar ao banco, usando o Servidor IIS 7.5, porém através do IISExpress, que inicia diretamente pelo Visual Studio Web 2013, a conexão ocorre normalmente.

Dados da Conexão:

> Connection String:
>   Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LocalIIS\secondsite\App_Data\aspnet-secondsite-91d3d8bf-0c8d-4f0a-9165-96960db8ab1b.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-secondsite-91d3d8bf-0c8d-4f0a-9165-96960db8ab1b;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False

Provider:

> .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server

Type:

> Microsoft SQL Server

Version:

> 11.00.3000

Comment: Fabiano, já viu se o sql server ta executando ? Porque pelo VS não precisaria de uma instancia do sql server no computador. Esse erro geralmente acontece quando o sql server ta desligado.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta apenas

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LocalIIS\secondsite\App_Data\aspnet-secondsite-91d3d8bf-0c8d-4f0a-9165-96960db8ab1b.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Comment: Retornou o mesmo erro!